# Two functions calling each other - C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function

I'm writing a program that writes all safe chains made of plutonium and lead for given length. A chain is safe if there are no 2 plutoniums next to each other.This is the solution from my textbook:

All safe chains length `n` that end with lead are made by adding lead to all safe chains length `n-1` that end with lead + all safe chains length `n-1` that end with plutonium.

All safe chains length `n` that end with plutonium are made by adding plutonium to all safe chains length `n-1` that end with lead.

I wrote code in C++ but it doesn't work because I have two functions that are calling each other so when I compile the program compiler says:

```
error: 'Plutonium' was not declared in this scope
```

This is my code:

```
void Lead(int k)
{
    if(k == 1)
    {
        x[1] = 'O';
        write();
    } else
    {
        x[k] = 'O';
        Lead(k-1);
        Plutonium(k-1);
    }
}

void Plutonium(int k)
{
    if(k == 1)
    {
        x[k] = 'P';
        write();
    } else
    {
        x[k] = 'P';
        Lead(k-1);
    }
}
```

I tried writing `void Plutonium();` in declaration of function `void Lead();` but it didn't work.

Is there a way to fix this or a different solution that won't leed to this problem?

Comment: just add a function declaration?

Comment: Make use of foward-declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
void Plutonium(int k);

void Lead(int k)
{
    if(k == 1)
    {
        x[1] = 'O';
        write();
    } else
    {
        x[k] = 'O';
        Lead(k-1);
        Plutonium(k-1);
    }
}

void Plutonium(int k)
{
    if(k == 1)
    {
        x[k] = 'P';
        write();
    } else
    {
        x[k] = 'P';
        Lead(k-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I wrote that, but without `int k` in parenthesis

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. It really fixed big issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Did you write function prototypes on top of your file?

```
void Lead(int k);
void Pultonium(int k);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a function before you use it so that the compiler knows how the function looks like. Just add `void Plutonium(int k);` somewhere before your `Lead` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need *function prototypes*.

```
void Lead (int k);
void Plutonium (int k);

/**
 * All of your code goes down here
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "forward declaration" on top of your code:

```
void Lead (int k);
void Plutonium (int k);
```